# tar doesn't archive all files although the log says otherwise

Tags: bash, shell, tar

I was running this command line:

```
mysql -h $dbHost -u $dbUser --password=$dbPasswd -N -B -e \
"use cms; select uri from file_managed;" | grep public: | sed \
's/public:\/\//\/amk_aco_data\/cms\//g' | xargs -d "\n" tar -czvf /tmp/cmspublicfile.tgz
```

and it was working just fine up until a week ago.
But now instead of archiving ~2k files, I get only 300 files inside the archive.
If I run it separately and save SQL query to a file:

```
mysql -h $dbHost -u $dbUser --password=$dbPasswd -N -B -e \ 
"use cms; select uri from file_managed;" | grep public: | sed \ 
's/public:\/\//\/amk_aco_data\/cms\//g' > files.toarchive
```

and then

```
tar -T files.toarchive -czvf /tmp/cmspublicfile.tgz,
```

it works as expected and I get my ~2k files inside archive.
I'm guessing the problem has to do with xargs, but I have no clue why it stopped working.

Some explanations: the SQL query prints out list of file URLs.

Can anyone give me any idea what should I check?

Comment: Did a uri get entered that contains an embedded newline and that's somehow causing `tar` to choke later?  Can you compare the last file that gets added to the tar with the next line in `files.toarchive` and see if there's something troublesome with the next file?  I don't know why it'd work with `-T` then though. . .  Perhaps run the whole thing with `set -x` and see what the command looks like when it is failing?

Comment: tar command doesn't fail, it finishes successfully. It even prints out all files that it is archiving, but then when I open the archive, most of the files are missing.
The last line in tar log and in files.toarchive is identical. It seems that it skips some of the folders inside

Comment: Are you running both commands as the same user, so it's not a problem reading the files as one user or something like that?

Comment: Same user, same permissions on all files as well

Comment: xargs also "breaks" on path/filenames containing space. Any chance a recently-introduced item has an embedded space?

Comment: This sounds like there are too many files for `xargs` to handle and it ends up running `tar` **twice**. Where the second run deletes the first tarball entirely.

Comment: Etan, thank you. That sounds like a good reason :) Any idea then how can I fix? Or just use the file option?

Answer (score 1):

you skip xargs and usr tar -T - which will read the file names from stdin

so the lat part will be:

```
| tar -T - -czvf /tmp/cmspublicfile.tgz
```

which is more similar to the working version

the complete command should be something like this:

```
mysql -h $dbHost -u $dbUser --password=$dbPasswd -N -B -e \
"use cms; select uri from file_managed;" | grep public: | sed \
's/public:\/\//\/amk_aco_data\/cms\//g' | tar -czvf /tmp/cmspublicfile.tgz -T -
```

Comment: not sure though why the original version stopped working - my guess is that xargs or tar have problems with to many arguments

Comment: Command lines have a length limit. `xargs` was designed to work around that but running a command *more than once*. The problem is that if a command runs more than once to the *same output file* without appending to it you lose the first output file. That sounds like what is happening here.

Comment: `-T -` is going to have problems with filenames with newlines in them (so will the original but at least you *can* get that to work correctly with `xargs` and can't with this).

Comment: Thanks! But isn't | is also taking stdout of the last command and passes it as as stdin to the next one? Can you please show me how the new command should like? I can't seem to make it work.